# CSS is and isn't overridden

Tags: html, css

How do I make sense of below from Firefox dev console "Inspector" tab?

[image]

The final effect is that this rule is *effective*, and it only becomes ineffective when I un-checkmark *both*, normal and crossed-out.

Comment: please check your html file, i think you have multiple link tags like this:

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>

Comment: @PetePearl Indeed I do, thanks, though I'd like to know if there's downsides to this, as the HTML is written by a third-party library.

Comment: this may slightly affect the performance of your application. css file will be downloaded once but applied twice by the browser

Comment: @PetePearl Feel free to post as answer, I'll accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check your html file, i think you have multiple link tags like this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'> 
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
```

this may slightly affect the performance of your application. css file will be downloaded once but applied twice by the browser